# why I can't get localStorage at ios9 portal web page?

Tags: javascript, safari, local-storage

I want to overwrite my localStorage with cookie when it is not enabled in safari(ios9, portal web page), and I got null with `window.localStorage`

I have try to defined localStorage by `Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {})`, and I got an error: TypeError: Attempting to change configurable attribute of unconfigurable property;

It's just like run `Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {configurable: false, value: null})` in safari. And then I can't get localStorage or overwrite it any more.

you can run this in your safari.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {configurable: false, value: null}).
```

And then, I have tried like this, but nothing work.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {configurable: true, value: {}).  // TypeError: Attempting to change configurable attribute of unconfigurable property.  
localStorage.setItem = function(){} // TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'localStorage.setItem = function(){}').
```

how can I fix it? even with **proto** and on.

I find this problem in ios9, portal web page. but you can reproduce it on any Safari Browser with `Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {configurable: false, value: null})`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to replace the localStorage *API* with a blank object. If you could do that then it would *break* localStorage in the page, not empty the stored data.

To reset it, use `localStorage.clear();`.

Comment: I apologize for my bad English, and I mean 'overwrite' but not 'reset', I want to overwrite localStorage with cookie